# Trying to create a basic dropdown menu with basic CSS, won't open up when clicked on

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So far I've tried to use this code:

CSS Code:

```css
/*global*/
html,
body {
  width: 100;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  font-family: Avenir, sans-serif;
}

/*functions*/

.multi-level,
.item ul,
.nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
#menu:checked ~ .multi-level,
.item input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML :

```html
<body>
  <p style="font-family: 'Avenir'; text-align: center">
    "What is this website about?" Info about select Macs and frequently asked
    questions.
  </p>

  <div class="nav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
    <label for="menu">&#9776</label>
  </div>

  <div class="multi-level">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="A" />
      <label for="A">Mac Mini</label>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2005-2006 (PPC)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2006-2010 (Polycarbonate Mini*)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2010-2018 (Aluminium Mini*)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2020-Present (M1 Mini)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The dropdown menu isn't working for some reason, I've tried adding  `visibility: visible;` and `visibility: show;` doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried to use Firefox and Safari, doesn't work on either of them could it be a browser related issue?

**Note**: I'm on the latest versions of both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this selector doesn't select anything:

```
#menu:checked ~ .multi-level {
    display: block;
}
```

Your `div.multi-level` isn't a sibling of `#menu`, it's a sibling of `.nav`. But [there's no CSS parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), so the only way to really fix this problem with a pure CSS solution is to restructure your HTML. You could get rid of `div.nav`, or you could move `div.multi-level` inside of `div.nav` right after `label for="menu"` or whatever else works for you.

Alternatively, you can use a JavaScript solution to toggle a class on one or more elements.